# How I Can Attach Object Into Mixamo Animation & Model

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, 3d-view, armature

I have question, i downloaded an a animation and model from [mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/)
But i cannot attach my gun & object into the animation can anybody help?

I tried to "track to" modifier but its brokes the object and i cannot join them its says "**no mesh data to join**"

Here is video for my problem, i tried to make parent with bone but eventually it's broke the animation;
[Video](https://youtu.be/ye06tohx51w)

Comment: Holding rifle - These two answers might help -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198580/animation-issue-in-sniper-gun-reload/198961#198961 - and this one -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226867/parenting-and-animating-bone-to-an-empty-without-going-to-pose-mode/227026#227026

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I'm so sorry im new at this forum but thank you so much for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Select the specific bone you would like to attach your object to. Then in the constraints tab for your object, select "Child Of". Select the armature, then the specific bone you want to attach your object to. At first it may appear in an odd position, but if you select the button 'Set Inverse' this usually fixes it.

Hope this helps!